# ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_rnn_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

Any ideas how can I solve problem shown below? With the information that I found on the web it is associated with problem of reusing tensorflow scope however nothing works.

```python
ValueError: Variable rnn/basic_rnn_cell/kernel already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "/code/backend/management/commands/RNN.py", line 370, in predict
    states_series, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=batchX_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)
  File "/code/backend/management/commands/RNN.py", line 499, in Command
    predict("string")
  File "/code/backend/management/commands/RNN.py", line 12, in <module>
    class Command(BaseCommand):
```

I tried for instance something like this

```python
with tf.variable_scope('scope'):
 states_series, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=batchX_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)
```

and this

```python
with tf.variable_scope('scope', reuse = True ):
 states_series, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=batchX_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)
```

and this

```python
with tf.variable_scope('scope', reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE ):
 states_series, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=batchX_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Does this happen when you run the model for the first time (upon opening a new python console)?

If not, you need to clear you computational graph. You can do that by putting this line at the beginning of your script.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! I couldn't find any solution for some time, so I had to restart Spyder environment every time I wanted to run my NN! You saved me!

Comment: Thank you, restarting kernel and reloading dataset was so annoying until I found this.